# undeclared identifier FBLinkShareParams

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, frameworks

I dont know what is happening, but I cant use FBLinkShareParams.

I followed the tutorial, copied the facebooksdk.framework to my project, but this still happening.

Someone have an idea? What can I do?

Thanks and sorry my english.

Comment: Please share the tutorial link or the code you have written to understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share

FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
Undeclared identifier on FBLinkShareParams

Comment: is there any file named as FBLinkShareParams.h in your header folder of FacebookSDK.framework ???

Comment: Yes!! that is the problem I guess

Comment: If your problem has been solved then please either accept or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Download https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk project

and run FBShareSample project from the extracted folder. I hope you can cross check from this project what is the issue on your side. As you haven't shared any error information I cant help you more than this right now.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed out:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```